# How to exactly use react-navigation in this example

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, react-navigation

I am trying to learn react-navigation. At the moment I am getting stuck with the error:

```
Cannot read property 'navigate' of undefined
TestComponent.render
    TestComponent.js:17:12
TestComponent.proxiedMethod
    createPrototypeProxy.js:44:29
<unknown>
    ReactNativeStack-dev.js:1863:24
measureLifeCyclePerf
    ReactNativeStack-dev.js:1610:15
ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._renderValidatedComponentWithoutOwnerOrContext
    ReactNativeStack-dev.js:1862:33
ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._renderValidatedComponent
    ReactNativeStack-dev.js:1872:39
ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.performInitialMount
    ReactNativeStack-dev.js:1696:62
ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent
    ReactNativeStack-dev.js:1655:164
Object.mountComponent
    ReactNativeStack-dev.js:1327:38
ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.performInitialMount
    ReactNativeStack-dev.js:1703:39
```

So here is my code

**index.android.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import DemoStore from './src/stores/DemoStore';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import PoolListComponent from "./src/components/PoolListComponent";
import TestComponent from "./src/components/TestComponent";

export default class TestApp extends Component {
  render() {
    const nav = StackNavigator({
      Home:  {screen: TestComponent},
      Pools: {screen: PoolListComponent}
    });


    return (
      <TestComponent store={DemoStore} />
    )
  }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('TestApp', () => TestApp);
```

**TestComponent**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Button, StyleSheet, View} from 'react-native';


export default class TestComponent extends Component {

  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Home',
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    const { navigate } = this.props.TestApp;
    return (
      <View>
        <Button
          title="Pool overview "
          onPress={() =>
            //navigation.navigate('Pools')
            console.log(this.props.TestApp)
          }
        />
      </View>
    );
  }

}
```

I am not sure how to pass the StackNavigator on to my TestComponent in `index.android.js`. I tried to pass it as a property like so:  `<TestComponent store={DemoStore} navigation={nav}/>` but this also didn't work.

Running on:

1. "react-native": "0.48.1",
2. "react-navigation": "^1.0.0-beta.15"

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are a bit confused. First you need to create your navigator and then render in your main component and then you can react `this.props.navigation` in your screen components.

**Example**

```
export default class TestApp extends Component {
  render() {
    const Navigator = StackNavigator({
      Home:  {screen: TestComponent},
      Pools: {screen: PoolListComponent}
    });


    return (
      <Navigator store={DemoStore} />
    )
  }
}
```

---

```
export default class TestComponent extends Component {

  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Home',
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    return (
      <View>
        <Button
          title="Pool overview "
          onPress={() =>
            navigate('Pools')
          }
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes I am confused. And now I am not confused anymmore.Thanks for your help